# Is there an alternative way, aside from sleep(), to make an AutoIt script wait before executing the next function?

Tags: automation, autoit

```
#include <IE.au3>

    Local $oIE = _IECreate("http://www.demo.com/")
    Local $oLinks = _IELinkGetCollection($oIE)
    Local $iNumLinks = @extended
    _IELinkClickByIndex($oIE, Random(0, $iNumLinks))

    Sleep(60000)

    _IEQuit($oIE)
```

In this script, after opening a random link, I want it to wait for the specified time, but it looks like `sleep()` is not working properly sometimes; it's waiting forever, and sometimes it's waiting longer than the `sleep()` time I set!

Is there any way to make that page wait for one minute before closing IE without using the `sleep()` command?

Comment: You could use `AdLibRegister` to call a function after a given amount of time. Whe the first call inside this function will be `AdLibUnRegister`, it might work as you expect.

Comment: Thats not true.
Sleep will always be correct by a ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick

```
Local $oIE = _IECreate("http://www.demo.com/")
Local $oLinks = _IELinkGetCollection($oIE)
Local $iNumLinks = @extended
_IELinkClickByIndex($oIE, Random(0, $iNumLinks, 1), 0)

Sleep(60000)

_IEQuit($oIE)
```

Wait times were different because the page load time(which is inconsistent) is added.
By setting the 3rd parameter to zero _IELinkClickByIndex will not wait for the link to load hence not adding the sleep time.